# Replace or change position in columns and sort the index Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, count, multiple-columns

I'm having troubles with the sorting of my counts generating my df so basically I'm running a for to use value_counts in each column but the problem comes when the is a few colums in the new df that are not sorted in a single way so there is columns like this:

[image]

I would like to have just one order for this columns either way yes, no don't know or any order but the same for the 3 columns and also they share the 3 options just because it doesn't appear any value with Don't know doest appear in the first 2 columns yes,no so I would like to add Don't know at the end, copy or replace the other 2 columns with the same options as column 3. I tried to explai it the best I could, this is my code:

```
li = []

for i in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    value_counts = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
    li.append(value_counts)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Because different values in columns is problematic join to one DataFrame, you can create multiple ouputs depends of data:

```
np.random.seed(202)
    
cat1 = ['more','less','no idea','same','other']
cat2 = ['cat1','cat2','cat3']
cat3 = ['Yes','No', "I don't know"]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(cat1, size=(10, 2)), columns=list('BD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(cat2, size=(10, 3)), columns=list('CFH'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(cat3, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('AIEG'))
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
              A      B     C        D             E     F             G     H  \
0           Yes   same  cat2    other            No  cat1  I don't know  cat2   
1  I don't know  other  cat1     more            No  cat1            No  cat3   
2  I don't know   less  cat3     less            No  cat3            No  cat1   
3            No   less  cat1     more            No  cat2            No  cat3   
4            No  other  cat1     same           Yes  cat1           Yes  cat2   
5            No   less  cat3    other            No  cat2           Yes  cat3   
6  I don't know  other  cat2    other  I don't know  cat1  I don't know  cat1   
7  I don't know   more  cat2  no idea            No  cat3  I don't know  cat2   
8            No   less  cat3     same  I don't know  cat1           Yes  cat3   
9           Yes  other  cat2     same  I don't know  cat3           Yes  cat3   

              I  
0  I don't know  
1           Yes  
2  I don't know  
3  I don't know  
4  I don't know  
5           Yes  
6           Yes  
7            No  
8           Yes  
9  I don't know
```

---

```
#columns with Yes, No, I don't know values to seperate DataFrame
mask = df.isin(['Yes','No', "I don't know"]).all()
cols1 = df.columns[mask]

    
df11 = pd.concat({i: df[i].value_counts() for i in cols1}, axis=1)
print (df11)
              A  E  G  I
No            4  6  3  1
I don't know  4  3  3  5
Yes           2  1  4  4

#all another columns to another DataFrame
cols2 = df.columns[~mask]
df22 = pd.concat({i: df[i].value_counts() for i in cols2}, axis=1)
print (df22)
           B    C    D    F    H
other    4.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
less     4.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
more     1.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN
same     1.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
cat2     NaN  4.0  NaN  2.0  3.0
cat3     NaN  3.0  NaN  3.0  5.0
cat1     NaN  3.0  NaN  5.0  2.0
no idea  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I liked your response but it gives me only NAN in all dataframe, this yes no is just one part from the entire df so I can use iloc to just do it in the respective columns could you help me with this?

Comment: @Eduardomaker are same values e. g, Yes and No in all columns? then use `reindex(['Yes','No'])`

Comment: no actually in all the columns has diferent index than ['Yes','No']

Comment: @Eduardomaker - Answer was edited.

Comment: I liked this I'll wil use it in my code and test thank you

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, Use `sort_index()`:

```
value_counts = df.iloc[:, i].value_counts().sort_index().to_frame().reset_index()
```

Based on the comment, consider the following example:

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,'a',2]})
s['a'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

produced:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

and:

```
s['a'].astype(str).value_counts().sort_index()
```

results:

```
1    1
2    1
a    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: it gives me this error:

'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Probably your index consists of different data types. Consider casting them before applying using something such as astype(str).

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit?

Comment: I'm going to follow with your suggestion of casting them, so what do you mean about casting them?

Comment: Please, look at the answer again.

Comment: I liked the answer it helps but it gives me the counts of NAN